# How to evaluate attributes inside an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### My problem

I am working on an angular component that displays data for a user object. The corresponding template looks as follows and works as intended:

```
<div>
  <h1>Information on user {{$ctrl.user.name}}</h1>

  <p><a href="#!/users/">Back to user list</a></p>

  <dl>
    <dt>Name:</dt><dd>{{$ctrl.user.name}}</dd>
    <dt>Native language:</dt><dd>{{$ctrl.user.nativeLanguage}}</dd>
    <dt>Preferred language:</dt><dd>{{$ctrl.user.preferredLanguage}}"></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

This produces the expected output:

```
Information on user Thomas
Back to user list
Name: Thomas
Native language: de
Preferred language: en
```

The possible values for the two languages are either two-character iso codes or the special values '??' for 'not chosen' and '--' for 'other'.

I now wanted to create an angular directive to show images of the corresponding flags next to the language text.

I tried this:

```
angular.
module('flag').
controller('FlagController', ['$scope',
    function FlagController($scope) {
    }
  ]).
directive('flag',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
         lang: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: 'flag-template.html'
    };
  }
);
```

With this directive template:

```
<span>{{lang}}</span><img ng-src="img/{{lang}}.png" />
```

and the modified component template:

For Thomas, this produces the expected output:

```
Information on user Thomas
Back to user list
Name: Thomas
Native language: de (german flag)
Preferred language: en (english flag)
```

However, for James who has the two special language values, the output looks like this (because there are no image files "img/--.png" and "img/??.png":

```
Information on user James
Back to user list
Name: James
Native language: ?? (broken image)
Preferred language: -- (broken image)
```

So I attempted to supply two different directive templates depending on the language value. I split the directive template into two files:

**flag.template.flags.html**

```
<span>{{lang}}</span><img ng-src="img/{{lang}}.png" />
```

**flag.template.no-flags.html**

```
<span>{{lang}}</span>
```

And then modified my directive as follows:

```
angular.
module('flag').
controller('FlagController', ['$scope',
  function FlagController($scope) {
    var self = this;
    console.log("FlagController, scope=", $scope);
  }
]).
directive('flag',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        lang: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: function getTemplate(elements, attributes) {
        console.log("- lang=", attributes.lang);
        
        if (attributes.lang) {
          if ('??' === attributes.lang || '--' === attributes.lang) {
            return 'flag/flag.template.no-flags.html'
          } else {
            return 'flag/flag.template.flags.html'
          }
        }
        return 'flag/flag.template.no-flags.html'
      }
    };
  }
);
```

However, this is not working as attributes.lang does not contain the evaluated value (i.e. 'de', 'en' or '??') but always contains '{{$ctrl.user.nativeLanguage}}' or '{{$ctrl.user.preferredLanguage}}' and therefore always returns 'flag.template.flags.html'.

### My question

Is there any way to either evaluate the value of attributes.lang inside the getTemplate() function or to make sure the value is evaluated before being passed to the "lang" attribute of the  directive?

Comment: Unrelated: don't use flags for languages. Flags represent countries, not languages. Many languages are spoken in several countries. Many countries have several official languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single template:

```
<span>{{lang}}</span>
<img ng-if="lang !== '--' && lang !== '??'" ng-src="img/{{lang}}.png" />
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that the language probably doesn't change during the session. So you may want to use one-time bindings for performance: `<span>{{::lang}}</span>` `<img ng-if="::(lang !== '--' && lang !== '??')" ng-src="img/{{::lang}}.png" />`